# haskell, counting how many prime numbers are there in a list

Tags: list, function, haskell, primes

i m a newbie to haskell, currently i need  a function 'f' which, given two integers, returns the number of prime numbers in between them (i.e., greater than the first integer but smaller than the second).

```
Main>  f 2 4
1
Main> f 2 10
3
```

here is my code so far, but it dosent work. any suggestions? thanks..

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f x y 
  | x < y = length [ n | n <- [x..y], y 'mod' n == 0] 
  | otherwise = 0
```

Comment: `Main> f 2 4`
`2`
this is my result, but u know, between 2 and 4, there s only 1 prime number, 3!so the result suppose to be 1 instead of 2....

Comment: I hope Prof van Deemter doesn't decide to set another assessment because your to stupid and lazy to, not only do the assessment yourself but to even change the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Judging from your example, you want the number of primes in the open interval (`x`,`y`), which in Haskell is denoted `[x+1 .. y-1]`.
- Your primality testing is flawed; you're testing for factors of `y`.
- To use a function name as an infix operator, use backticks (`), not single quotes (').

Try this instead:

```
-- note: no need for the otherwise, since [x..y] == [] if x>y
nPrimes a b  =  length $ filter isPrime [a+1 .. b-1]
```

Exercise for the reader: implement `isPrime`. Note that it only takes one argument.

Comment: Good, two extra comments: 1. [a+1, b-1] should be [a+1 .. b-1], and 2. I think the asker on purpose didn't use backticks, because stack-overflow would interpret them `like this` in some reversed fashion.

Comment: @Tarrasch: 1. thanks for the correction; 2. I'd considered that, but backticks work fine in code blocks, which the OP apparently knows how to use.

Comment: sorry for being a noobie...i dont really get what s this mean `nPrimes a b  =  length $ filter isPrime [a+1 .. b-1]`  how dose it gonna fit my code?

Comment: nPrimes a b = function that computes the number of primes between a and b   /  isPrime  = a (yet to write) function that tests if a number is prime  /  filter = a standard function that filters those elements of a list that satisfy a predicate (like for example isPrime)  / length = a standard function that gives the length of a list, in that case the length of the list of prime numbers between a and b, and that is the result of nPrimes.

Comment: You need to write isPrime. But if you have it, you can also replace the guard in your list comprehension with isPrime n

Comment: @user704420: `filter isPrime [a+1 .. b-1]` is equivalent to `[p | p <- [a+1 .. b-1], isPrime p]`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what your list comprehension does.

```
n <- [x..y]
```

Draw n from a list ranging from `x` to `y`.

```
y `mod` n == 0
```

Only select those `n` which evenly divide y.

```
length (...)
```

Find how many such `n` there are.

What your code currently does is find out how many of the numbers between x and y (inclusive) are factors of y. So if you do `f 2 4`, the list will be `[2, 4]` (the numbers that evenly divide 4), and the length of that is 2. If you do `f 2 10`, the list will be `[2, 5, 10] (the numbers that evenly divide 10), and the length of that is 3.

It is important to try to understand for yourself *why* your code doesn't work. In this case, it's simply the wrong algorithm. For algorithms that find whether a number is prime, among many other sources, you can check the [wikipedia article: Primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Answer (score 0):

I you want to work with large intervals, then it might be a better idea to compute a list of primes once (instead of doing a isPrime test for every number):

```
primes = -- A list with all prime numbers
candidates = [a+1 .. b-1]
myprimes = intersectSortedLists candidates primes
nPrimes = length $ myprimes
```